# Is there an embedded visual (PHP) parser for Microsoft Word?

Tags: php, parsing, ms-word

I am writing about code that I have written for documentation, mainly in PHP. I also have other languages that I will write about but I am wondering what the easiest way to display code within a word document. I could just import a print screen of a Notepad++ document but I would like an easy way to include code into Microsoft Word without having to print screen it every time I want to make a change. I am looking for something that will allow me to edit the code within word, but obviously not be functional. I would like there to be some sort of visual parsing so that similarly to Notepad++ it is more readable.

Comment: @dqhendricks what would you suggest using?

Comment: It sounds like this is to produce a report or documentation

Comment: @dqhendricks I am writing about my code as documentation as Matt has just stated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to print screen in Notepad++.  You can export/copy the text as RTF and preserve syntax highlighting and formatting.

I'm not on my PC at the moment, but the option is either under the TextFX menu, or the Plugins menu.

Works very nicely.

Edit:

[image]

This menu, press 'Copy RTF to Clipboard', and you can paste into Word.

Comment: how do I then import this into word?

Comment: @Tim It seems to have some style but it is unreadable due to a dark blue background. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I've never had this issue, for me it copied and pasted preserving the exact style in Notepad++.  Perhaps Word has highlighted the background and you'll need to set it to white?  Use the highlighter tool in Word.

Comment: You're welcome! This is exactly what I did for my code documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using word to document your code, you could instead check out a document markup language called Latex.

It allows for easy documentation of code(and math) and is therefor a really good tool for creating scientific reports.

http://www.latex-project.org/

Here is a basic tutorial on how it works:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SoDv0qhyysQ

(This youtube video explains the basics)